# is having a static singleton getter in an interface a bad practice?

Tags: java, java-8, singleton

Let's say I have this interface:

```
    public interface MyInterface {

        static MyInterface getSingleton() {
            return MyDefaultImplementation.getSingleton();
        }

        //declare some methods

    }
```

and this class:

```
final class MyDefaultImplementation implements MyInterface {

    private static final MyInterface mySingleton = new MyDefaultImplementation();

    static final MyInterface getInstance() {
        return mySingleton();
    }

    private MyDefaultImplementation() {
       //...
    }

    //implement interface methods
}
```

I was wondering if the getSingleton() method of MyInterface should exist or if it is more correct to make MyDefaultImplementation and its getInstance method public. It it's the case, what are the main scenarios in which it makes sense having the getSingleton method in the interface?

Thank you for your time

Comment: I think `singleton` and `interface` can't go along at all. If someone provides `MyOtherImplementation`, the contract of `MyInterface.getSingleton()` would be broken.

Comment: So if I want to implement a singleton class, it should never extend an interface?

Comment: No, `MyDefaultImplementation` can be a singleton, but not the interface `MyInterface`, as it can (should) be implemented for multiple times (as this is the intention of an interface). Hence it cannot be guaranteed, that `MyDefaultImplementation.mySingleton` is the only instance of `MyInterface`.

Comment: I understand, but what if I intend to have a singleton class from the beginning but still I want to create an interface for this class, but I do not want this interface to be implemented by any other class in the future. What is the correct approach for this?

Comment: Actually, don't use an interface at all. As I already mentioned, the intention of an interface is to allow multiple (and ultimately pluggable) implementations, thus there is no way to prevent this. So if you don't want that, you must not use it.

Answer (score 3):

The point of an interface is to avoid having the "client" code which uses the interface know about the implementation details of the class.  This is critical for future maintenance, as you are designing in the ability to replace the interface's implementation at a future point in time.

If your interface contains a reference of how to "obtain" the underlying implementation, then in order to update your code, you now need to rewrite your interface, and redeploy it.  This "change" in the interface based on implementation change, and not "interface" change (adding or removing methods) strongly implies that you are not working within the original intent of the system's design.

Default methods are a relatively new addition to Java.  They were not added in the past because without them, it would be impossible to combine implementation into an interface.  The addition of them is permitting a lot of scenarios where implementation is defined in the interface, and that is blurring the line between interfaces and abstract classes.  In my opinion, that robs the interface of its utility.

Finally, you are using this to create a `Singleton` which is a sign that you are using pre-Object-Oriented design practices in your Object-Oriented system.  Singletons are ways to introduce unscoped globals.  Unscoped globals are what made C/C++ programs very hard to maintain.  You would better align your code into an Object that is passed into the methods requiring it.  If you need only one instance of that object, an improved code structure can have only one instance created (one call to new) and it will be clear which methods use the object, and which ones don't.

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering if the getSingleton() method of MyInterface should
>   exist

Your interface becomes both a interface and a factory.
So API and implementation become a same part.

If API and implementations are in the same component (jar for example), in practice, it will not change many things.

But if API and implementations are not in the same component but in two distinct jars : `api` and `impl`, things are different.
It means that your client has to update both the `api` and the `impl` component as you add a new  implementation in `impl` that you return in the `getSingleton()` method of the `api`.

You didn't change the contract but only the implementation but the client has to update both `impl` and `api`.
It is undesirable and counter intuitive and it defeats the purpose to separate api and implementation.

Comment: `Your interface becomes both a interface and a factory` there's like tons of these in java-8 with default methods

Comment: It is right. I specified also : "If API and implementations are in the same component (jar for example), in practice, it will not change many things." JDK may be seen in this way for java developers (even if technically, it is not only one jar)

Comment: don't get me wrong, I upvoted; just wanted to make that clear, that unless this is split in separated jars, I don't really see a benefit in this. I actually like returning factories from interfaces since default methods appeared.

Comment: I get your point. I updated a little. I looking a little in JDK 8 classes. Could you give me example of factory implementation in the interface ? For example   `default Stream<E> stream() {
        return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), false);
    }` delegates the factory processing to `StreamSupport()`.

Comment: I was thinking about `static` and `default` methods... for example `Predicate#isEqual` or `Function#identity`

Comment: Thank you. These look like more as utility or logic factory methods than factory methods that return  a specific implementation of a class/interface as the op question. I referenced `StreamSupport.stream()` as it does this kind of logic as most of public static methods of this class but we can see that this is not in an interface.

Answer (score 1):

It's more correct to use third object which will provide object implementations.

Like: `DI.getBean(MyInterface.class) -> return myDefaultImplementation`.

Or: `SingletonServiceFactory.getBean() -> ...`

Examples:

- light-4j: [SingletonServiceFactory](https://github.com/networknt/light-4j/blob/master/service/src/main/java/com/networknt/service/SingletonServiceFactory.java#L296)
- [Simple showcase](https://github.com/ruslanys/highloadcup/blob/master/src/main/java/me/ruslanys/highloadcup/DI.java#L26)

Answer (score 1):

An interface *can’t* be a Singleton. An implementation class may be a Singleton, but that doesn’t prevent *other* implementation classes of the interface. Therefore, a method named `getSingleton()` in an interface, suggesting that the interface was a Singleton, is clearly wrong. While the implementation class is a Singleton, the factory method’s purpose is to hide this implementation from the code using the interface, so it’s contradicting to try to export an information about a property of this hidden implementation class, like its Singleton nature, through the API.

It’s different when it comes to factory methods in interfaces, compare to `Stream.empty()` or Java 9’s `List.of()`, which do not tell whether the underlying implementation will be a Singleton or not. They provide factories for specialized implementations, which are considered to be fundamental enough to be part of the interface’s API.

This has to be your main consideration too, when thinking about providing factories in an interface. The existence of these implementations is coupled with the interface, even if the actual implementation class is not, so you will always have to bundle the interface with appropriate working implementation classes from then, even if an application might only use the interface to implement it on its own. There might be implementations deserving such treatment. However, if your expectation is to always have this sole Singleton implementation only and no other implementations, there is little reason to use an interface at all.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is **wrong**.

Your interface `MyInterface` should not be aware of the implementation `MyDefaultImplementation`.
Only your implementation should be aware of your interface.